# Dialog context issue - Android

Tags: java, android, oop, dialog

I have created a dialog box like so using a custom layout:

```
    dialog = new Dialog(FetchMenu.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_iab);
    dialog.show();
```

I am now trying to edit a textbox within 'layout.custom_dialog_iab' for example:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.all_topics_unlock_button);
text.setText("Purchased");
```

**My Question:** How do I get the right context to be able to edit the textboxes?

P.S. I have tried 'dialog.getContext()' but still keep throwing null pointers?

Comment: have you tried `TextView text = (TextView)dialog. findViewById(R.id.all_topics_unlock_button);` after showing dialog ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.all_topics_unlock_button);
```

Note the `dialog.` in front of findViewById

regular findViewById() will search your activity layout rather than the dialog layout.